# Удалить строку в хедере сайта

Tags: content, meta

Как удалить название темы Wordpress в хедере своего сайта?
http://joxi.ru/1A5XpyGhKx9Xx2

В файле header.php нет этой строки. Непонятно где она засела.

```
<meta content="Deals v.1.0.0" name="generator"/><meta content="Theme Junkie Framework v.1.0.5" name="generator"/><style type="text/css">
```

Comment: Общение на русском здесь.

Answer (score 1):

Эта строка может генерироваться из каких-либо `*.php` файлов, которые идут в комплекте с вашей темой.

Сразу без деталей темы сложно что-то сказать, но я бы попробовал поискать в файлах темы эту строку:

`<meta content="Theme Junkie Framework v.1.0.5" name="generator"/>`

Сразу станет понятно откуда корни растут.

Comment: а как легче всего найти по файлам эту строку? Не каждый же файл php открывать.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь IDE (например JetBrains PhpStorm или Github Atom) для этого, там должна быть возможность поиска чего-либо (в вашем случае строки) среди всех файлов темы.

Comment: Если у вас Linux и вы не хотите использовать IDE, то тут есть подробное описание как это сделать: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16956810/finding-all-files-containing-a-text-string-on-linux

Comment: То же самое можно поискать в интернете и для вашей операционной сети, если же у вас отлична от Linux.